# For $f\in H(U)$, find a bound on $|f(0)|$ given separate bounds of $|f|$ on $\partial U^{+}$ and $\partial U_{-}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic in the unit disc $U$ and continuous on $\bar{U}$.  Suppose $|f(e^{i\theta})|\leq1$ for $\theta\in[0,\pi)$ and $|f(e^{i\theta})|\leq\frac{1}{4}$ for $\theta\in[\pi,2\pi).$  Show that $|f(\theta)|\leq\frac{1}{2}$.

I'm not sure at all how to prove this -- so far I've only come up with the obvious observations that anybody would notice at first glance.  The maximum modulus principle implies that $\frac{1}{4}\leq|f(0)|\leq1$ and even if we could apply the mean-value property, we would still only end up with $|f(0)|\leq\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{5}{8}.$  Intuitively (if the conclusion is true), there cannot be a sharp change from $|f|\approx 1$ on the upper half circle and $|f|\approx\frac{1}{4}$ on the lower half circle (I'm picturing something similar to a bump function here on the line $[0,2\pi]$ with the bump occuring at $\theta=\pi$), and this being dictated by the holomorphicity in the interior of the disc.  From this intuition I thought somehow Harnack's inequality could be applied to the real and imaginary parts of $f$, but this seems to be going off the mark a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function

$$g(z) = f(z)\cdot f(-z).$$

By the assumptions, $g$ is holomorphic on $U$ and continuous on $\overline{U}$, and $\lvert g(e^{i\theta})\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{4}$. By the maximum modulus principle,

$$\lvert f(0)\rvert^2 = \lvert g(0)\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{4}\,.$$

Comment: Okay, so then we have $||g||_{T}=||f||_{T^{+}}||f||_{T^{-}}.$  By symmetry and the conditions on $f$, we conclude $||g||_{T}\leq\frac{1}{4}.$  Since $g$ is holomorphic and continuous on $\bar{U}$, we have by the maximum modulus principle $|g(z)|\leq\frac{1}{4}.$  Therefore, $f(z)=\frac{1}{4f(-z)}$ and so $|f(0)|\leq\frac{1}{4}|\frac{1}{f(0)}|$, i.e. $|f(0)|=\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: You don't necessarily have $\lvert g\rvert \equiv \frac14$ on the boundary, and even with that, $g$ need not be constant. But you have $\lvert g\rvert \leqslant \frac14$ on the boundary. That is everything you need.

Comment: I made a correction to my comment as you were writing yours (though I didn't have time to finish rewriting the conclusion as $|f(0)|\leq\frac{1}{2}$ before the comment edit expiration.  I was trying to write out the details of the answer in my head and accidently also reasoned that the minimum of $|g(z)|$ on the boundary was $\frac{1}{4}$ as well, which is not the case.

Comment: No, $\lvert g\rvert$ need not be constant - if it is, $g$ is also constant. But the maximum principle says $\lvert g(z)\rvert \leqslant \frac14$ in the disk, in particular $\lvert g(0)\rvert = \lvert f(0)^2\rvert \leqslant \frac14$.

Comment: Hmm...in regards to the second part of your comment, I see now that even if $|g|\geq\frac{1}{4}$ too, it would not imply $g$ was constant; however, it does imply $|g|$ is, no?

Comment: How does $|g|$ being a constant imply $g$ is?  What about $re^{it}$?

Comment: Ah, you meant constant only on the boundary? That's possible for non-constant functions, of course. I thought you meant constant on the entire disk.